# Image onclick change image, play sound and tooltip

Tags: javascript, image

I have an image and when I am clicking on it then the image should change to another picture. Moreover, at the same time an audio file should be played and a tooltip should appear.

And it would be great that it will be switched to the original state after X seconds, so I can click on it again and again without refreshing the whole site.

I was thinking about an image with the javascript onclick method, like:

```
<img src="../img/book_closed.jpg" id="image1" onclick=...">
```

But I have no idea how to handle the other events...

This is my code so far: http://pastebin.com/PHnzLsQq

Comment: Have you tried something? can we see your `js` code?

Comment: I have updated my post with a link to my current code

Answer (score 0):

So you need to write an onclick event.

Use the setimeout to return the page back it's original state.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onImageClick() {
    // Set new state
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Set back to original state
    }, 4000);
}
</script>

<img src="../img/book_closed.jpg" id="image1" onclick="onImageClick();">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you check my pastebin and tell me how I should handle it with the playing audio and tooltip?

Comment: So play audio file in html: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp from 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp
You can set img.src = "NewImageSource"; to change image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use js

```
var oImg = document.getElementById( 'image1' );
oImg.addEventListener( 'click', function() {

    oImg.src = //another image

});
```

This would switch to another image when clicked

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already handled the image switching. It remains to play an audio file and that a tooltip will appear. How can I do that at the same time?

Comment: Tooltip would appear automatically I believe. Its audio you may focus on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MGY53/3/

For audio:

```
function imgChange(el,soundfile)
{
    if (el.mp3) {
    if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
    else el.mp3.pause();
} else {
    el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
    el.mp3.play();
}
}
```

Click:

```
onclick="imgChange(this, 'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg');"
```